# What is the Ruby equivalent for Rails' "has_one" method?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a Ruby application. In there I have two classes, that have a 1:1 relation. In Rails I would use ActiveRecord's `has_one` method on each function. But in Ruby, and without a database, I am not sure what to do.

How do I define relations / associations between classes in Ruby?

Edit: 
This is not about a specific problem I have at the moment. I just wondered how I would express Rails `has_one` (respectively `has_many`, `belongs_to`) in pure Ruby code. The two classes I mentioned above are:
1. A class that runs a search algorithm.
2. A class that I use to handle user input that I need during the search process and that also displays results of intermediate steps and statistics.

Maybe what I am asking for doesn't make sense as it can be expressed without a dedicated method like `has_one`? Or because it is never needed without a DB?

Comment: do you really need `has_one` without a DB?

Comment: Outside of the ActiveRecord pattern there are several others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I didn't try anything as I thought this is a classic case of knowing or not knowing the right method/class. I will add some information to the  question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define relations as attributes like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :one, :many
  def initialize
    @many = []
  end
end

class Bar
end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Bar.new
other_bar = Bar.new
foo.one = bar
foo.many << other_bar
foo.many << bar

p foo.one
# => #<Bar:0x21d5c1a0>
puts foo.many
# => [#<Bar:0x538613b3>, #<Bar:0x21d5c1a0>]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if no database is needed.

`attr_accessor` declares public properties for fetching and writing the declared instance variables.

After the instance is created you can add the relationship.